# Shuffle some elements of an array with a specific step

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to shuffle some elements of an array with a specific step.

I have this array of object :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "aze54aze",
    "boosted": false
  },
  {
    "_id": "94v2d9e3",
    "boosted": false
  },
  {
    "_id": "999f5a8az4",
    "boosted": false
  },
  {
    "_id": "e9d29a9g",
    "boosted": true
  },
  {
    "_id": "f8f2a9f6a",
    "boosted": false
  },
  {
    "_id": "pe55z8a",
    "boosted": false
  },
  {
    "_id": "pvazpd97",
    "boosted": false
  },
  {
    "_id": "ft8azefze",
    "boosted": true
  },
]
```

I want the boosted objects to be shuffled within the array with a step of two objects between them. In order to not put them all at the beginning of the array, I need them to be "hidden" in the array.

That means that the first boosted object will go at the first position, then two normal objects, then the second boosted object, then the other normal objects.

Can I achieve this with Lodash built-in functions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using *native* `ES6` javascript features like `filter`, `reduce` methods and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

First of all, you should separate the `boosted` and `normal` array *items*. Then create a new array where first boosted object will go at the first position, then two normal objects, then second boosted object and so on...

I used `splice` method in order to `remove` items from `normal` or `boosted` *array* after I added them to my result array. *Why this ?* Because at the end I need to `concat` the remaining elements to my result.

```js
var arr = [ { "_id": "aze54aze", "boosted": false }, { "_id": "94v2d9e3", "boosted": false }, { "_id": "999f5a8az4", "boosted": false }, { "_id": "e9d29a9g", "boosted": true }, { "_id": "f8f2a9f6a", "boosted": false }, { "_id": "pe55z8a", "boosted": false }, { "_id": "pvazpd97", "boosted": false }, { "_id": "ft8azefze", "boosted": true }, ] 

var boosted = arr.filter(item => item.boosted);
var boosted_copy = boosted.slice();
var normal = arr.filter(item => !item.boosted);
var result = boosted.reduce((res, item, i) => {
   res.push(boosted_copy.splice(0, 1)[0], ...normal.splice(0, i * 2 + 2));
   return res;
}, []).concat(boosted_copy, normal);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks a lot ! If there is not enough normal items (too much boosted items), boosted items will all go at the end of the array once the last normal item has been reached right ?

Comment: @Elwyn, check it now.

Comment: @Elwyn, don't forget to accept answer in order to help ohter people

Answer (score 1):

With ES6 you could achieve that by using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const data = [ { "_id": "aze54aze", "boosted": false }, { "_id": "94v2d9e3", "boosted": false }, { "_id": "999f5a8az4", "boosted": false }, { "_id": "e9d29a9g", "boosted": true }, { "_id": "f8f2a9f6a", "boosted": false }, { "_id": "pe55z8a", "boosted": false }, { "_id": "pvazpd97", "boosted": false }, { "_id": "ft8azefze", "boosted": true }, ]

const shuffleMeSoftly = (d, size) => {
  let g = d.reduce((r,c) => (r[c.boosted] = [...r[c.boosted] || [], c],r), {})
  return g.false.reduce((r,c,i) => {
     let nt = g.true[Math.floor(i/size)]
     r = i%size == 0 ? [...r || [], ...(nt ? [nt] : []), c] : [...r || [], c]
     return r
  }, [])
}

console.log(shuffleMeSoftly(data, 2))  // true every 2 false
console.log(shuffleMeSoftly(data, 3))  // true every 3 false
```

With lodash and ES6 [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) you could:

```js
const data = [ { "_id": "aze54aze", "boosted": false }, { "_id": "94v2d9e3", "boosted": false }, { "_id": "999f5a8az4", "boosted": false }, { "_id": "e9d29a9g", "boosted": true }, { "_id": "f8f2a9f6a", "boosted": false }, { "_id": "pe55z8a", "boosted": false }, { "_id": "pvazpd97", "boosted": false }, { "_id": "ft8azefze", "boosted": true }, ]

const shuffleMeSoftly = (d, size) => {
   let grouped = _.groupBy(d, 'boosted')
   let chunks = _.chunk(grouped.false, size)
   return _.reduce(chunks, (r,c,i) => [...r, ...(grouped.true[i] ? [grouped.true[i]] : []), ...c], [])
}

console.log(shuffleMeSoftly(data, 2))   // true every 2 false
console.log(shuffleMeSoftly(data, 3))   // true every 3 false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

By using [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#groupBy)/[chunk](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#chunk) and then [reduce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#reduce).

It really is 2 lines if you get the `chunks` into the reduce instead of being its own variable but I left it for readability etc.

Comment: Beautiful answer!. Don't forget to add explanation for your algorithm. Anyway, +1.